# What could cause large latency creating Lucee components on request start?

Tags: coldfusion, lucee

We're switching from Railo to Lucee 5.2.3 and noticed that there is sometimes a large latency on request startup. I think I've boiled it down to a function that is loading about 30 components with `createObject('component', ...)` into the Request scope. On Railo, this list will load within a second. On Lucee it can take about 20 seconds, but not always. It seems to consistently occur if we need to dynamically create a datasource or connect to a datasource other than the primary global datasource for the environment. After the initial load of these component objects, it will load within a second. I can't figure out what could be causing this initial performance hit. The .cfc files are in subdirectories under the ROOT directory of the site, so I'm just using the standard `<cfset Request.Helpers[ThisHelper] = createObject("component","cfcs.componentFileName") />`. This function isn't calling the `init()`, it is just creating the objects. Also, this function is not where we dynamically create any datasources, it's exclusively creating objects in the request scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't comment on Lucee specifically, but know that traditionally we've always avoided excessive object creation in CF. Could any of the objects get moved to application scope, created once and re-eused by all visitors?

Might also be something todo with Lucee being OSGi based rather than Classloader based. Perhaps some overhead on OSGi service startup?

Comment: Yeah, things just built up to this point based on some old decisions. We were hoping to avoid a massive regression test, but it looks like that isn't possible. Thanks John!